# How should I test Gmaps4rails generated maps?

Tags: selenium, capybara, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails-1.3.0 to render a few maps in my rails-3.0.7 application. When the map loads, it already has a few markers set. The users get to select which type of markers they want to see by getting to click on a few checkboxes. This works fine in all versions of FF, Chrome and IE that I have checked.

So, now I wanted to write automated test cases to check this functionality. For this, I wrote rspec-2.6.0 request examples which are run through capybara-1.1.2 using the selenium-2.14.0 driver. The test is able to load the map fine with all of the markers showing up correctly. However, no markers are removed when the test unchecks one of the checkboxes. I inserted a debugger statement at the end of test and then checked the error console in the browser. It had the following message:

```
console is not defined
http://127.0.0.1:51643/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js?1323052026 Line 196
```

Checking the relevant file showed the following function:

```
Gmaps4RailsGoogle.prototype.clearMarker = function(marker) {
console.log(marker);
return marker.serviceObject.setMap(null);
};
```

I then noticed that during normal operation, a no. of such log messages are displayed in the firebug console. The selenium webdriver profile doesn't have firebug and nor do I expect all my users to have firebug.

Should a console.log() call be there in any javascript file post-development? If yes, what's the way to test it with a rendering driver, in particular with selenium?

Comment: apneadiving confirmed on github that he had removed this line in the latest code. So, I have removed it too and everything is working fine.